# python list id(L) and id(L[:])

Tags: python, list, copy

I'm curious about the difference and relationship between `id(L)` and `id(L[:])`, where `L` is a list.

The official documentation says this about id():

> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

But I don't understand why `id(L)` and `id(L[:])` have different values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`L[:]` produces a copy of the list. Its a whole new list contain the same items as L. As a result, its stored in a different place in memory and has a different id.

Comment: It is the same as `L[slice(None)]` by the way.  And it is a shallow copy.

Comment: so, you mean, even if I just run `id(L[:])`, the interpreter will also create a shallow copy of the list and return the new address, and then release the newly copied list after `id(L[:])` is done? Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: @taijirobot, that's exactly what happens.