# Mutable and immutable object in Python

Tags: python, immutability, mutable

I am trying to understand the mutable/immutable object in python. The example below, I expect to get the same object ids for all id(**) but # list 4 is not. How can I explain the reason that only #list 4 gives a different object id?
Thank you.

```py
# list 1
la = [1,2,3]
print('la=', la, ', id(la)= ',id(la))

# list 2
la[0]=9
print('la=', la, ', id(la)= ',id(la))

# list 3
lb=la
print('lb=', lb, ', id(lb)= ',id(lb))

# list 4
lc=la[:]
print('lc=', lc, ', id(lc)= ',id(lc))
```

```
la= [1, 2, 3] , id(la)=  2678849549576
la= [9, 2, 3] , id(la)=  2678849549576
lb= [9, 2, 3] , id(lb)=  2678849549576
lc= [9, 2, 3] , id(lc)=  2678844118664
```

Comment: The slice `la[:]` creates a (shallow) copy of the list. `lb = la` just creates an alias. This has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: list 4 slices (creates a segment from list la and returns it as a new array).

Comment: some_list[:] returns a ***new*** list (a shallow copy), akin to list(some_list) which also returns a ***new*** list object. With this information, what is the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python list id(L) and id(L\[:\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475982/python-list-idl-and-idl)

Answer (score 1):

The `[:]` syntax is a shortcut for [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), which creates a new (shallow copy) object from the original object. A shallow copy is a new high-level object, so the nested objects will be only referenced (no new copies of the nested objects are created). Example,

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
id(a) == id(b) # True
c = a[:]
id(a) == id(c) # False
id(a[0]) == id(c[0]) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way: A slice needs to be a different object, a copy of the original:

```
In [15]: la=[1,2,3]                                                                                                   

In [16]: la[:2]                                                                                                       
Out[16]: [1, 2]

In [17]: la=[1,2,3]                                                                                                   

In [18]: lb=la[:2]                                                                                                    

In [19]: lb[0] = 5                                                                                                    

In [20]: lb                                                                                                           
Out[20]: [5, 2]

In [21]: la                                                                                                           
Out[21]: [1, 2, 3]
```

`la[:]` is a slice, although in this form it is a slice that returns the entire list.

However a slice works the same way with a tuple, which is an immutable type:

```
In [22]: ta=(1,2,3)                                                                                                   

In [23]: ta[:2]                                                                                                       
Out[23]: (1, 2)
```

etc.

The difference from a list is that you can't do `ta[0] = 5`. That makes a tuple immutable, and a list mutable.

Assigning to `la` or `ta` does not change any object, these are only names (aliases) of objects:

```
ta=[1,2,3]
ta=4
```

The second assignment did not change the list, it changed the name `ta` to refer to the integer `4`. The list `[1,2,3]`, if there is no other reference to it, will be garbage collected and destroyed.